# Excel Macro UI design: How to let the user select several inputs

Tags: excel, vba

The following question is to a lower extent a coding, but rather a UI design problem:

Suppose I have a button somewhere calling a macro when pressed. Now the macro needs two different inputs -- say, two ranges. Then it does something with the inputs and writes the result somewhere. What is the best way to let the user specify these two input ranges?

If it were not two, but only one input, it would be easy: We would let the user select the input and then, after the button being pressed, the macro could look for the selected range and evaluate that. Does anyone have any idea how a user-friendly solution in case of two inputs could look like?

Comment: Use either two refedit boxes on an UserForm, or use two `Application.Inputboxes` with type on 8 (range)

Answer (score 3):

For example you can get the user to enter two ranges like these (the default selections of `A1:A10` and `B1:B10` can be removed)

You would also use error checking before proceeding further (in case user had cancelled)

```
Sub RangeExample()
Dim rng1 As Range
Dim rng2 As Range
Set rng1 = Application.InputBox("Select first range", "Range 1", Range("A1:A10").Address, , , , , 8)
Set rng2 = Application.InputBox("Select second range", "Range 2", Range("B1:B10").Address, , , , , 8)
End Sub
```

Comment: @JohnB As for error handling you can do this:     `Dim myErr as Long`
    `On Error Resume Next`
    `Set column1 = Application.InputBox("Please enter column to ckeck", "Range to Check", , , , , , 8)`
    `MyErr = Err`
    `MsgBox "You cancelled the input!", , "Error " & MyErr`

Comment: `+1` I realized I have forgotten to vote up while commenting ;)